# Difference between using aliases and not using them

Tags: sql, scope

Consider the following relations

```
Seller(idSeller, ...)
Car(idCar, ...)
Customer(idCustomer, ...)
Sale(idSeller, idCar, idCustomer, ...)
```

Are the following queries equivalent? (Will they produce the same results?)

***Q1***

```
SELECT *
FROM Seller e, Car r, Customer c, Sale s
WHERE s.idSeller = idSeller AND s.idCar = idCar AND s.idCustomer = idCustomer;
```

***Q2***

```
SELECT *
FROM Seller e, Car r, Customer c, Sale s
WHERE s.idSeller = e.idSeller AND s.idCar = r.idCar AND s.idCustomer = c.idCustomer;
```

---

Note that this is not for a specific DBMS, but rather an exercise for SQL (for SQL-99 Standard).

Comment: Maybe?  Depends on how `s.idCustomer = idCustomer` gets resolved.  Many RDBMSs will say that the `idCustomer` is ambiguously defined.

Comment: Please learn to use the explicit JOIN notation instead of the old (pre-1992) implicit join notation: `SELECT *
FROM Sale s JOIN Car r ON s.idCar = r.idCar JOIN Seller e ON s.idSeller = e.idSeller JOIN Customer c ON s.idCustomer = c.idCustomer`.  You need to know how to read the old notation in case you come across it.  You should not write the old notation in any new SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to run these queries?

The first one shouldn't work on most RDBMS; it should throw an error about 'ambiguous column'.

You can't refer with the same name to different columns on different tables; that's why the aliases exist! The DBMS won't be able to identify which column you mean by `idCar` when more than 1 exists.

If by any chance this query did run, don't rely on the fact that the RDBMS chose the correct one.

Comment: Ops :) Yea, don't know why I wrote second @DaMike

Answer (score 1):

No, they are not equivalent. The first query has 3 errors.
You have 2 idSeller, idCar and idCustomer, making the references to these, without specifying the table, ambiguous.
You should specify which table they refer to, like in the second query.

The result is something like:

```
idSeller | idCar | idCustomer | idSeller | idCar | idCustomer
```

How can the DBMS know which one is the idSeller, idCar and idCustomer? You need to specify from which table they come.

Answer (score 0):

The two query are not equivalent because in the first you refer to wrong or ambigous column   `ss.idSeller = idSeller AND s.idCar = idCar AND s.idCustomer = idCustomer;

if you don't use the proper alias or table name the correct relation can't be done.  ..

The query could eventually work if the table contain the same column name but the result is not correctly related to you data and you expected resut